# Is this algorithm for searching for an item in a singly linked list correct?

Tags: java, algorithm, singly-linked-list

Step 1: BEGIN

Step 2: Accept the item to be searched

Step 3: Declare PTR as a pointer pointing to the first node
 and position marker pos = 0

Step 4: repeat steps 5 - 7 till PTR becomes NULL

Step 5: increment pos

Step 6: Check whether PTR.INFO is equal to ITEM, if it is, display ITEM is present in the linked list and its position pos and, EXIT

Step 7: PTR = PTR.LINK

Step 8: if PTR == NULL display ITEM is not present in the linked list

Step 9: END

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-an-element-in-a-linked-list-iterative-and-recursive/

Comment: at first glance i thought this is fortran or pascal until I noticed that ^ missing with pointers and that there is no NIL ;).   But for the question: depending how pos is defined, it does. Commonly/Usually indexes start with 0 in which case the position would be one off.  -- Still: this is not Java but pseudo code.

Comment: It's correct, but the IF in step 8 is redundant, since step 4 implies that PTR==NULL at this point.